# Cant initialize a 2d array/matrix to 0

Tags: c++, matrix, multidimensional-array, dynamic-programming, bottom-up

I am trying to initialize a 2d array (matrix) to 0 but, cant do it:

```
int longestCommonSubsequence(string text1, string text2) {
    int len1=0;
    len1=text1.length()+1;
    int len2=0;
    len2=text2.length()+1;
    int dp[len1][len2]={0};
```

Error:

```
Line 8: Char 16: error: variable-sized object may not be initialized
        int dp[len1][len2]={0};
               ^~~~
1 error generated.
```

I want initialize the matrix while declaring it. I do not want to use for loop.

Comment: `int dp[len1][len2]={0};` is not allowed. Use `std::vector`

Comment: Variable length array are not standard C++. Moreover, you can't just initialize to zero all the values by just assigning the whole array with zero. I'd suggest you to get a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/a/388282/11455384) and start to learn properly the language. C++ is not a language you can learn just by try and guess.

Comment: if `int dp[len1][len2];` did compile without error, then you are using a compiler extension. If you want to stay with it you need to read your compilers manual. However, its not really recommended, rather aim to write portable code

Comment: VLA is not part of C++ standard. This is possible since C has such feature and by default compiler allows to mix C with C++.

Comment: @MarekR OK, I will keep this in mind.

Comment: what compiler are you using? for gcc i suggest to use `-pedantic-errors` at least until you know what you are doing

Comment: You're using a VLA (an array with dimension that is not a compile-time constant).  A multi-dimensional VLA at that.  VLA's are not part of standard C++ at all.   If your compiler supports VLA's *at all* it is as a non-standard extension.  Let alone what it allows you to do with them (e.g. initialising elements on declaration).   Instead of using a VLA, use `std::vector`.   In your case, `std::vector<std::vector<int> > dp(len1, std::vector<int>(len2, 0))` will be one way of declaring and initialising as you wish.

Comment: Umm, I was solving a coding problem on a website!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variable sized arrays are not standard C++, for arrays of constant length you just use value-initialisation syntax:

```cpp
int arr[4][4]{};
```

Alternatively, use C++ collections of variable length:

```cpp
int rows = 4;
int columns = 4;
std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec(rows, std::vector<int>(columns));
```

Comment: @rushabhvg you may want to consider C++ standard collections instead. I updated my answer just in case